# SSRS 2012 Internal Server Error 500 when loading in browser

Tags: .net, sql-server, reporting-services

I have spend a whole day today to figure this out.

When loading the reporting manager or server from browser with either :

```
    http://localhost/reports 

    http://machine-name/reportserver
```

It is showing the 500 internal Server Error

I found in the event viewer of windows the problem you see on the bottom of the post

This is my research. 
I thought assembly is missing so checked the presence of it and compared it to a working machine.

Everything was ok, the files where exact in the same folders, also the user rights looked like an exact copy. 
I reinstalled the .net framework 3.5.1 from Configuration->Add Remove Programs->Turn On Off windows features. Also the .net framework 4.5.1 from the add remove programs.

No change. I cleaned the registry with CCleaner as i spotted differences in the found keys when searching System.Web.Services (On the wrong machine). Found a lot of keys called "MissingDependecies" with as value System.Web.Services assembly. After the cleaning the registry still did not look like on the working machine. Problem was not solved.

I installed a new instance of SQL and Reporting Server but no result.

Does any one has an idea of where this problem might be and how to solve it ? 
I followed all possible solutions on the internet I could find.

Removing the oracle refference from machine.config did not work. 
Rebuild the database multiple times. No Result. 
Search for hints in the process monitor, but besides the messages same as below no other results.

I think there is something wrong with .Net frameworks installation and the registry but do not know how to fix it. Tried all .net framework repair tools and sql server repair.

The description for Event ID 1334 from source ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0 cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

Failed to initialize the AppDomain:ReportManager_MSSQLSERVER_0

Exception: System.Web.HttpException

Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Services, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

StackTrace:    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironmentAndReportErrors(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)

InnerException: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException

Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Services, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

StackTrace:    at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai)
   at System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler..ctor(VirtualPath configPath, Boolean supportLocalization, String outputAssemblyName)
   at System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()

InnerException: System.BadImageFormatException

Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Services, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

StackTrace:    at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)

Comment: Can you access the Reporting Services Configuration Tool via Programs|Microsoft SQL Server 2012|Configuration Tools|Reporting Services Configuration Manager?

Comment: Yes that is no problem.